# If $\Gamma\subseteq\mathbb C^n$ is a lattice and $A=\mathbb C^n/\Gamma$, why is $H^1(A,\mathbb C)\longrightarrow H^1(A,\mathcal{O}_{A})$ a surjection?

Tags: homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, modular-forms

I am reading my teacher's lecture notes on a course about modular forms and I am stuck at the following problem:

Assume $\Gamma\subseteq\mathbb{C}^{n}$ is a lattice and $A:=\mathbb{C}^{n}/\Gamma$ is an $n$-dimensional torus.

Then there exists a diagram of short exact sequences

$\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\kern-1.5ex\xrightarrow{\ \ #1\ \ }\phantom{}\kern-1.5ex}
\newcommand{\ras}[1]{\kern-1.5ex\xrightarrow{\ \ \smash{#1}\ \ }\phantom{}\kern-1.5ex}
\newcommand{\da}[1]{\bigg\downarrow\raise.5ex\rlap{\scriptstyle#1}}
\begin{array}{c}
0 & \ras{} & \mathbb{Z} & \ras{} & \mathbb{C} & \ras{e^{2\pi i\cdot}} & \mathbb{C}^{*} & \ras{} & 0 \\ & & \da{=} & & \da{} & & \da{} & &  \\
0 & \ra{} & \mathbb{Z} & \ra{} & \mathcal{O}_{A} & \ra{} & \mathcal{O}^{*}_{A} & \ra{} &  0\text{.}
\end{array}$

This induces a diagram of long exact sequences

$\begin{array}{c}
H^{1}(A,\mathbb{Z}) & \ras{} & H^{1}(A,\mathbb{C}) & \ras{} & H^{1}(A,\mathbb{C}^{*}) & \ras{} & H^{2}(A,\mathbb{Z})\\
\da{=} & & \da{} & & \da{} & &  \da{=}\\
H^{1}(A,\mathbb{Z}) & \ra{} & H^{1}(A,\mathcal{O}_{A}) & \ra{} & H^{1}(A,\mathcal{O}_{A}^{*}) & \ra{} &  H^{2}(A,\mathbb{Z})\text{.}
\end{array}$

Questions:

(1.) How do the two maps $\mathbb{C}\longrightarrow\mathcal{O}_{A}$ and $\mathbb{C}^{*}\longrightarrow\mathcal{O}^{*}_{A}$ come about? Are they induced from $\begin{array}\mathbb{C}& \ras{a\mapsto(a,a,a,...)} & \mathbb{C}^{n} & \ras{} & A\end{array}$?

(2.) My teacher makes the claim that $H^{1}(A,\mathbb{C})\longrightarrow H^{1}(A,\mathcal{O}_{A})$ is a surjection. Why is that the case?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: (1.) These are the inclusions of locally constant (nowhere-vanishing) functions into holomorphic (nowhere-vanishing) functions resp.. (2.) You can identify $H^1(A,\mathcal{O}_A)\cong H^{0,1}(A)$ and $H^1(A,\mathbb{C})\cong H^{1,0}(A)\oplus H^{0,1}(A)$ by explicitly calculating this cohomology group and the map corresponds to the projection under these isomorphisms, which you can show by comparing the de Rham and Dolbeault acyclic resolutions. But maybe I'm missing a more straightforward argument..